# C# Using WMI To Query LogicalDisk Information

Tags: c#, wmi, performancecounter

I'm looking to get performance information for the disks on my local computer using WMI. According to the documentation for Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfDisk_LogicalDisk (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394261(v=vs.85).aspx), it looks like I should just be able to query the information and get the values.

However, when I run the code I get "0" for each value for the properties.

```
var selectQuery = new SelectQuery("Select * from Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfDisk_LogicalDisk");
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(selectQuery);

foreach (ManagementObject disk in searcher.Get())
{
    foreach (PropertyData property in disk.Properties)
    {
        var propertyValue = property.Value; // 0 value.
    }
}
```

I have also queried Win32_PerfRawData_PerfDisk_LogicalDisk and I do get actual raw values. Of course, I would rather have the formatted data instead of the raw data. The documentation for converting the raw data to the formatted data seems to be lacking when it comes to using WMI.

Any idea why I am getting 0 for each value?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example just tested this

You can use the WMI [Performance Class Counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392738%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). An example of this would be polling the PerfDisk_LogicalDisk

```
ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfDisk_LogicalDisk");
foreach (ManagementObject service in mos.Get())
{
    foreach (PropertyData propData in service.Properties)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", propData.Name, propData.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still returning 0 for m["AvgDiskBytesPerRead"]. Is it returning a value when you run it?

Comment: Still gives me the same result of 0 for each property. Is it possible I may have some configuration wrong? I assume you're not getting 0 for the value.

Comment: perhaps .. I can't tell what could be wrong on your end .. but this code works on my Windows 7 Ultimate local machine.. do you have WMI showing up when you right click on myComputer and select manage..?

Comment: Yep, I show it under Computer Management. It's odd because I can get other WMI information just fine (such as Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Memory).